# jquery-ui autocomplete for json shows all data when i type into input

Tags: json, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

i have problem with using jquery-ui auto-complete for json. say, my json query return from myurl/users/listid and this is the returning data:

```
[{"label":"test@gmail.com"},{"label":"omg@hotmail.com"},{"label":"bad@yahoo.com"}]
```

and this is my jquery script for autocomplete.

```
$("#search-query").autocomplete({
    source: '/users/listid'
});
```

when i type something into my #search-query input box, this all three email id are shown regardless what i type. it should narrow it down to what it matches to the character i try to type. but it doesn't.

okay. this is something wierd. when i change something like following script, everything works perfect.

```
var data = [{"label":"test@gmail.com"},{"label":"omg@hotmail.com"},{"label":"bad@yahoo.com"}];

$("#search-query").autocomplete({
    source: data
});
```

i have totally no idea what has gone wrong. please guide me. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the source is an `url`, `autocomplete` expect your own business logic in that `url` to filter out the options. The paramater `term` would be sent to the url with the input value.

Comment: Please read http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/. Your should update your server side code to do the filtering.

Comment: done. i did it in my controller with parameter and the trick is at jquery parameter -> data: {term: request.term}.